# How often is IPsec used in IPV4 networks?

Tags: ipv4, ipsec

If I disable it on my computer will I lose anything?

Answer (score 1):

IPSec is used to establish a virtual private network (VPN). If you don't use any VPNs, I doubt disabling it will hurt anything.

Comment: IPsec is only available for use with IPv6. IPv4 doesn't even recognize that it exists.

Comment: @Deoetpatria - There are many uses of IPSec, I run IPv4 IPSec tunnels across my networks.

Comment: @Deoetpatria That is patently false. IPsec works just as well with IPv4. RFC 6071, *IP Security (IPsec) and Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Document Roadmap*, states in its introduction that "IPsec and IKE can be used in conjunction with both IPv4 and IPv6." It also works with many other protocols, see section 8 of that RFC, "Other Protocols That Use IPsec/IKE", which has 10 subsections.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you (or someone administrating your computer) have configured IPSec to communicate securely with other hosts, disabling it won't hurt.